# python-how can I pass arguments to "map_async"?

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing

My program is simply:

```
def mult(name,title):
    while True:
        name = str(name)+str(title)

pool = multiprocessing.pool(processes=5)
pool.map_async(mult,?...?)
pool.join()
```

My problem is how to pass the multiple arguments in "map_async()". I tried to supply them as an array like "map_async(mult,['go','stop']), but an exception is raised for missing arguments.

I want to pass the two arguments to function "mult" using map_async. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starmap_async worked but my app couldn't run with it due to it accessing the camera; I oversimplified my function in this question for the sake of simplicity. I resorted to "Popen()" instead and managed to run the app. Thank you very much Erik White; starmap is a great function that I might use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using Python 3, you can use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) or [starmap_async](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap_async):

```
args = [("name", "title"), ("name2", "title2")]

def mult(name,title):
    return str(name)+str(title)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
result = pool.starmap(mult,args)

>> ['nametitle', 'name2title2']
```

[See it run](https://repl.it/repls/FantasticWingedCone)

If you really want to use async:

```
args = [("name", "title"), ("name2", "title2")]

def mult(name,title):
  return str(name)+str(title)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
map_result = pool.starmap_async(mult,args)
result = map_result.get(timeout = 2)

>> ['nametitle', 'name2title2']
```

[See it run](https://repl.it/repls/JudiciousBewitchedBlogclient)

I changed your `mult` function because it doesn't make any sense. It starts an infinite loop with `while True` and each loop assigns a value to `name`, but the value is never returned.

It is extremely unclear what result you are hoping for, but hopefully this will start you on the right track.

Comment: could you shed more light on "...,product(names,repeat=2))?? thank you for the helpful answer, but I didnt understand how to pass my 2 arguments to the function

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how to use it. The `product` call was just for the linked question'

Comment: ? product is a function in itertools ! your answer is vague and doesn't work and the function is wrong even ! this answer from 2011 gives better explanation which you seem to have copy-pasted from it !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments

Comment: I made a typo in the function call which I have fixed, I also added links so you can see the code running. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with your `mult` function, but I have shown how you can use `pool.starmap` and `pool.starmap_async` with multiple variables.